# mongoose db.stats() equivalent

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using mongoose, and I need to get stats of database.

I know about `YourModel.collection.stats()`, but thats just for a collection, I need similar thing, but for the database.

Please dont suggest running the shell command. I want to do it using mongoose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `db.stats` on the `mongoose.connection` object:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function() {
  db.db.stats(function(err, stats) {
      console.log(stats);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to MrWhilihog's post, you can also get the data doing the following:

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.db.stats(function (err, stats) {
  console.log(stats);
});
```

This way you are able to get the stats later when your connection is already open.