# access db.serverStatus() of mongo in mongoose @3.6.20

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to use db.serverStatus() using mongoose@3.6.20

I have already use this // its working in mongoose updated version which is 5.0 above

[mongoose-db-stats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37831667/mongoose-db-stats-equivalent)

```js
mongoose.connect("mongodb://url");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.on("open", function() {
  db.db.stats(function(err, stats) {
    console.log(stats);
    callback(stats);
  });
});
```

something like this but from `db.on('open',function(){` this line is not working

I am using node -v `7.10.0`
monsoose -v `3.6.20`

If anything missing in question then please ask.

Comment: have you tried mongoose.connection. readyState

Answer (score -1):

```
let db = mongoose.connection;

db.db.command({serverStatus: 1}, function (err, result) { ... });
```